# Linq custom comparer for contains?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 lists. I want to compare every element with every element for both lists using LINQ (versus using say a nested loop). But, the Contains does not meet my needs because I need to do a custom comparison. I would imagine a custom comparer is what I need but not 100% sure.

I do not think this should be too difficult but not sure exactly the tool that I need for this. The 2 lists both contain distinct and different type of objects.

Update:

Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I have 2 lists (or enumerables) I could do something like this:

```
foreach(item i in list1)
  foreach(otherItemType in List2)
  {
    if ( CompareItem(x) ) do something;
  }
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
var matches = myList1.Where(t => myList2.Something(t) )
```

Where Something is a custom comparer, perhaps I can override the equals comparison? I could use the `.Contains` but I need to do my own logic for comparison.

Update:
I thought of using the `IEqualityComparer` but this is set to take types of T, T and T, Y. There may be some generic constraints that I could use to solve this problem. I felt this should be easy/simple.

Comment: Could you explain your requirements further, or provide some example data and expected results?

Comment: Override GetHashCode() so that different items return different hash codes, and the 'same' items return the same hash code. Then contains will work as it should (I think)

Comment: @PostMan - you should never bank on GetHashCode() returning different values for different items, only that it will always return the same value for items that are considered equal.

Comment: @Will A ahh thanks for that, never knew that! :)

Comment: @PostMan - np, glad to be of help.  Imagine the fun you'd have writing `GetHashCode() As Integer` for a Long - and making it satisfy the 'only equal if objects are equal'!

Comment: If you're performing side effects (the `do something;`), I would recommend you stick to the `foreach` loops, as it's more clear there are side effects.  A functional-looking piece of code should, IMO, be functional, and LINQ expressions are functional-looking.

Comment: @Strager I want to get my list of the matches and then run my foreach loop to "do something".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var matches = myList1.SelectMany(
    t1 => myList2.Where(
        t2 => t2.Something(t1)
    )
);
```

The inner `Where` is like your inner `foreach` loop, and the outer `SelectMany` joins the results after iterating through as in your outer `foreach` loop.

You can also make a function to do this for you (untested; can't recall extension syntax):

```
public static IEnumerable<T2> MultiCompare<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> first, IEnumerable<T2> second, Func<bool, T1, T2> comparer) {
    return first.SelectMany(
        t1 => second.Where(
            t2 => comparer(t1, t2)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to do this that is more clear? This is slightly difficult to read but appears to work.

Comment: @Curtis White, Well, you can make a function, as I just posted.

Comment: The extension syntax should be `...MultiCompare<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> first, ...` then `first.SelectMany(...`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had thought of an extension. You will get the credits after the min period is expired. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the sample below will do it.  Since *Any* takes a delegate you can define an arbitrary matching comparison between the two elements of the list.  If you need all elements to match, use *All* in place of *Any*.

```
[Test]
public void StackOverflow()
{
  var digits = new int[] {1, 2, 4, 9};
  var strings = new string[] {"1", "4", "5", "7"};

  var matches = strings.Where(s => digits.Any(d => d.ToString() == s)).ToList();

  // Prints
  // 1
  // 4

  matches.ForEach(x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [Enumerable.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx)?

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var list2 = new List<string> { "2", "4", "5" };

var matches = from i in list
              join s in list2 on i.ToString() equals s
              select i; // if you want to use the matching items from the 1st list

// there's no ForEach on Enumerable so you'd have to write the extension yourself (which is easy)
// or you could just output matches to a List first
matches.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

When it comes to joins I strongly prefer the linq query syntax, though you could equally use Lambda expression they usually look a bit messy...

Answer (score 0):

I had question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875005/how-would-you-go-about-making-a-list-comparable) a while back that may help you get started.